# CSS - Create a visible border on tab

Tags: css

Using an angularJS tab shown here:
[Example with required solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OWis.png)

I would like to add a border to the tab for visual impact. Here is the code I have for the following features, if anyone knows how to do it, please let me know! I would assume it is a CSS issue, but if not, can change.

```css
      md-tabs-canvas {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
      height: 48px; }
      md-tabs-canvas:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both; }
      md-tabs-canvas .md-dummy-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; }
        [dir=rtl] md-tabs-canvas .md-dummy-wrapper {
          left: auto;
          right: 0; }
      md-tabs-canvas.md-paginated {
        margin: 0 32px; }
      md-tabs-canvas.md-center-tabs {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center; }
        md-tabs-canvas.md-center-tabs .md-tab {
          float: none;
          display: inline-block; 
        }
```

```html
      <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="auto" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label="User Information">
                <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <div class="widget-header">
```

Comment: Can’t really tell what your problem/question is here. Do you have no clue how to add a border, or did you try something and it didn’t work?

Comment: please add an working jsfiddle link. thanks

Comment: No clue to be honest @04FS, I tried added border top and thought that would work but it hasn't. I just want to have a line showing for the top of the tab feature.